# Problema con la carga del navegador Internet Explorer controlado por Powershell

Tags: .net, windows, script, powershell

Estoy intentando hacer que mientras no este listo el navegador espere segundos hasta que este listo y se ejecute el código pero esto se lo salta y se ejecuta el código cuando no esta listo el navegador ¿cómo hago para que no ocurra esto?

```
 cls
 $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
 $ie.navigate2("https://www.youtube.com")
 $ie.visible = $true
 while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }    <---no esta funcionando
 $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")[16].outerHTML
 $ie.Quit()
```

Comment: al parecer ie.Busy no es muy confiable, fijate en este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/a/19344109/1423096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificar tu bloque de código de la siguiente manera:

```
 cls
 $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
 $ie.navigate2("https://www.youtube.com")
 $ie.visible = $true
 while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
 $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")[16].outerHTML
 $ie.Quit()
```

Pasando a utilizar la propiedad ***ReadyState*** (más información en el siguiente [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)).

El valor numérico **4** indica que la operación se completó.

Comment: Sigue sin ir me ejecuta $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")[16].outerHTML cuando esta cargando lo he provado poniendo sleep 16 solo y si me va pero esos segundos demas se pierden eso no es lo que quiero

Comment: Podés intentar cambiar la línea del while con lo siguiente:  for ($i=0; $i -le 200; $i++) {$ie.ReadyState; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10}. Con lo anterior podés ver si el valor va cambiando (deberían aparecer varios 1 y luego varios 3).

Comment: Estoy intentando ayudar! Mi comentario fue para ver si podías identificar si el valor no se registraba correctamente.

Comment: ya pero es que no entiendo porque no me va lo he probado de mil formas y nada te agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Has probado con otras páginas? En otro equipo diferente? Para ir descartando cosas...

Comment: si de hecho youtube no es l apagina donde estoy probando

Comment: a vosotros os funciona con el codigo de arriba

Comment: Yo lo he probado en 2 equipos diferentes y con varias páginas y me funciona cualquiera de los 2 métodos.

Comment: pues nose que puede estar pasandop a mi me da el error de no se puede llamar a un metodo vacio o null

Comment: alguien sabe como se solucionaría esto con selenium

Comment: con que versión de powershell ?

Comment: En los 2 equipos con la versión 5.1